# How to change independently the distance between ActionBar icons in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-icons

I don't want to change the distance between all icons, to have the same distance. I want to change the distance between each icon separately.

This what i have now:

[image]

And this is what i want to achieve:

[image]

And this is my menu.xml file. The `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` makes no difference.

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/sand_clock"
    android:icon="@drawable/sand_clock"
    android:title="@string/sand_clock"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:title="@string/timer"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView" />

    <item
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
    android:title="@string/refreshButton"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/homeButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title="@string/homeButton"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

How can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by defining a custom view in place of your action bar, [this link](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) helped me alot. Refer it.

Comment: Using this tutorial i cannot use the overflow menu button anymore. Is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: You can use an imageview with the overflow icon